# What does the "S_I" part mean in S_IRUSR etc?

Tags: history, posix

According to POSIX, `sys/stat.h` shall define a bunch of macro constants such as `S_IRUSR`. The "R" part obviously means "Readable" and the "USR" part "User" (the owner of the file.) Then what about the `S_I` part?

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html

Comment: The etymology tag question should go to Meta.

Comment: S for "stat", and I for "inode"? It's common to prefix identifiers to avoid confusion, and this part is probably very old ...

Comment: To avoid confusion _and_ clashes with other values, since those are #defined constants and they don't have separate namespaces

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224701/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-mode-mask-names-from-stat2-and-chmod2